# F#. Terminated due to timeout when solving Project Euler #3 problem

Tags: algorithm, f#, primes, prime-factoring

I told about that problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003

I am trying to solve this problem as follows:

```
open System


let isPrime n =
    match n with
    | _ when n > 3L && (n % 2L = 0L || n % 3L = 0L) -> false
    | _ ->
        let maxDiv = int64(System.Math.Sqrt(float n)) + 1L
        let rec f d i = 
            if d > maxDiv then 
                true
            else
                if n % d = 0L then 
                    false
                else
                    f (d + i) (6L - i)     
        f 5L 2L

let primeFactors n =
    let rec getFactor num proposed acc =
        match proposed with
        | _ when proposed = num -> proposed::acc
        | _ when num % proposed = 0L -> getFactor (num / proposed) proposed (proposed::acc)
        | _ when isPrime num -> num::acc
        | _ -> getFactor num (proposed + 1L) acc
    getFactor n 2L []


let pe3() =
    for i = 1 to Console.ReadLine()  |> int  do
        let num = Console.ReadLine() |> int64
        let start = DateTime.Now
        primeFactors num 
            |> List.max
            |> printfn "%i" 
        let elapsed = DateTime.Now - start
        printfn "elapsed: %A" elapsed

pe3()
```

There are results of my testing:

- Input: **10** Output: **5** Elapsed time: **00:00:00.0562321**
- Input: **123456789** Output: **3803** Elapsed time: **00:00:00.0979232**
- Input: **12345678999** Output: **1371742111** Elapsed time: **00:00:00.0520280**
- Input: **987654321852** Output: **680202701** Elapsed time: **00:00:00.0564059**
- Input: **13652478965478** Output: **2275413160913** Elapsed time:
  **00:00:00.0593369**
- Input: **99999999999999** Output: **909091** Elapsed time: **00:00:00.1260673**

But I anyway get Terminated due to timeout in **Test Case 5**. What can I do?

Comment: in `primeFactors`, replace `| _ when proposed = num -> proposed::acc` with `| _ when proposed*proposed > num -> num::acc`,  and it'll work.

Comment: @WillNess thank you for answer. unfortunately, I get the same error

Comment: @PoppyField can you share what the input is for test case 5?

Comment: Here's a couple of hints. If `k` is the smallest factor of `n` (other than 1) then `k` is prime. If `k` is the smallest factor of `n` then the smallest factor of `n/k` is at least as great as `k`. If there is no factor of `n` less than or equal to `sqrt(n)`, then `n` is prime.

Comment: All of those are easy to prove. The result is that `isPrime` will only be called with prime arguments and that `acc` will always be sorted (so it's not necessary to keep the list). Also, as mentioned in a comment above, you can terminate the search much earlier.

Comment: @SvenGrosen hi. no, I do not have access to them

Comment: but you have access to https://tio.run. Incorporate the change I proposed, and also as @rici has proposed, you don't need the function `isPrime` *at all* -- remove it, and the line where it is referenced further down. If that still doesn't get you through, incorporate the other suggestion by @ rici, have accumulator be not a list, but a number  - the last discovered factor. which *will be* the largest.

Comment: @WillNess thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
open System

let primeFactors n =
    let rec getFactor num proposed acc =
       match proposed with
       | _ when proposed*proposed > num -> num::acc
       | _ when num % proposed = 0L -> getFactor (num / proposed) proposed (proposed::acc)
       | _ -> getFactor num (proposed + 1L) acc
    getFactor n 2L []

let pe3() =
    for i = 1 to Console.ReadLine()  |> int  do
        printfn "%i" (primeFactors (Console.ReadLine() |> int64)).Head
pe3()
```

Thanks **Will Ness** and **rici**.

Comment: the very first element in the list will actually be the biggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write super sophisticated code for this challenge. A simple algorithm to enumerate a number's prime factors will do the trick. My code creates a `seq` of the prime factors, then finds the maximum, and prints it. The rest of the code shows a nice functional way of handling processing of lines read from standard input.

```
module Auxiliaries =

    let isNull (x : 'a when 'a : not struct) =
        match box x with
        | null -> true
        | _ -> false

    let refAsOption x =
        if isNull x then None else Some x

    let readLinesFromTextReader r =
        let tryRdLn (r : System.IO.TextReader) =
            try refAsOption (r.ReadLine ()) with _ -> None
        let gen r =
            tryRdLn r |> Option.map (fun s -> (s, r))
        Seq.unfold gen r

module Contest =

    let factors num =
        let next n =
            if n = 2L then 3L
            elif n % 6L = 1L then n + 4L
            else n + 2L
        let rec loop nn ct lf =
            seq {
                if ct * ct > nn then
                    if nn > lf then yield nn
                elif nn % ct = 0L then
                    yield ct
                    yield! loop (nn / ct) ct ct
                else
                    yield! loop nn (next ct) lf
            }
        loop num 2L 0L

    let euler003 n = factors n |> Seq.max

    let () =
        Auxiliaries.readLinesFromTextReader stdin
        |> Seq.skip 1
        |> Seq.map (int64 >> euler003)
        |> Seq.iter stdout.WriteLine
```